# Is there a more efficient way to write this code?

Tags: vb.net

I use this counter to track how many times in a row the button has been pressed. 
If another button is pressed the counter is reset to 0. I've not programmed in a long time and I'm certain this can be written in a more optimized way.

```
If counterd = 0 Then
    money = money + 1400
    counterd = counterd + 1
ElseIf counterd = 1 Then
    money = money + 1900
    counterd = counterd + 1
ElseIf counterd = 2 Then
    money = money + 2400
    counterd = counterd + 1
ElseIf counterd = 3 Then
    money = money + 2900
    counterd = counterd + 1
ElseIf counterd > 4 Or counterd = 4 Then
    money = money + 3400
    counterd = counterd + 1
End If

If money > 16000 Or money = 16000 Then
    money = 16000
End If
```

Comment: You are counting the number of buttons pressed in a row? I do not see any button press detection in the code nor any other logic. Please explain.

Comment: Little things you should master early; they'll pay off as you progress. First: Look at `If money > 16000 Or money = 16000`. First of all, you'll almost always want to use `OrElse` instead of `Or`. In an "or" situation, if the first condition is true then the whole expression is true. `Or` will evaluate both even if the first condition is true. `OrElse` will stop after the first one. This is called "logical shortcutting". It's faster. Not here really, but if your `Or` conditions are calling functions that can run a while you'll save a ton of time by not calling it when you don't have to.

Comment: Second: Look again at `If money > 16000 Or money = 16000`. That means if money is *greater than or equal to* 16,000, which is better written as `If money >= 16000`. This is general advice. In your specific case I wouldn't even bother with an `If` and instead I'd replace the last three lines with `money = Math.Min(money, 16000)`. So my last bit of advice is: learn the framework :) A little at a time though: there's way too much in .NET to learn in a few hours or days or even months. Good luck, and keep asking! I upvoted your question. Others should too. It's legit and it shows effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your logic can pretty much be represented in these 3 lines of code:

```
money = money + 1400 + (Math.Min(counterd, 4) * 500)
counterd += 1

If money > 16000 Then money = 16000
```

Or an even shorter version:

```
money = Math.Min(16000, money + 1400 + (Math.Min(counterd, 4) * 500))
counterd += 1
```

It's not the best readable version though, so you might want to break the first line into two or three steps/lines.

Both versions use `Math.Min` to select the minimum value out of two values. For example, `Math.Min(16000, anotherValue)` will always return `anotherValue` as long as it's less than `16000`. Once `anotherValue` becomes greater than `16000`, the `Math.Min` method will return `16000` instead.

### References:

- [`Math.Min` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.min?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Math_Min_System_Int32_System_Int32_).

Comment: Appreciate the answer, would it be possible for you to explain how the shorter version works?

Comment: @Lewis, you don't really need it explained. Just break it down into its constituent parts and then do the appropriate research to find out how that part works. When you understand each part, you understand the whole. It's actually even easier than that though because there are really only two things there. There are simple arithmetic operations that shouldn't require any explanation and there are two calls to `Math.Min`. If you write that code in VS you can click on the method name and hit F1 to go straight to the documentation for that method, or simply search the web for it.

Comment: @Lewis I've edited the answer and included a link to the `Math.Min` method documentation.